# How much volume do the cluster's ec2 workers have?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-eks

I want to know How much volume is available to each of `EC2` instances in an `EKS` cluster?

According to [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html), There are two types of `AMI`s:

1. `EBS-backed AMI`s with `16 TiB` available volume.
2. `instance store-backed AMI`s with `10 GiB` available volume.

Which one of them does the workers' AMI belong?

I create my EKS cluster using this [terraform module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest):

```
module "eks" {
  ...
  worker_groups = [
    {
      name                          = "worker-group-1"
      instance_type                 = "t2.small"
      asg_desired_capacity          = 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re using instances of type T2.small. This instance type is EBS-backed only and doesn’t have an instance store option.

According to the documentation that you mentioned, the size limit for an EBS-backed instance’s root device is 16 TiB. The actual size however depends on the volume sizes that you configure for the instances (I’m not sure but I think it defaults to 20 GiB). You can also add multiple EBS volumes to exceed the 16 TiB limit if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What do you mean by "the volume sizes that you configure for the instances"? I don't see any configurable option for volumes in the EKS Terraform module.

Comment: You can use “root-block-size” in the “terraform-aws-eks” module: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/WesleyCharlesBlake/eks/aws/latest?tab=inputs

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one more question: What happens when an ec2 instance runs out of the 20 GiB dedicated EBS. Does EKS autoscaler (if enabled) create a new worker node for that? Or the EBS storage gets increased?

Comment: No, Amazon EKS doesn't automatically scale up or out depending on disk space. You would have to set up monitoring and scale accordingly.

Comment: What about the provisioned EBS? Doesn't it get increased automatically?